# Getting the error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)

Tags: c

I tried to troubleshoot this and couldn't find the exact problem as to why I'm getting this error(error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
*outerD_P = outerD;) . I tried making innerD_P and outerD_P a ** but that didn't work. I'm sorry if it's a simple fix I'm still learning C. Thank you for the help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// PI is the ratio of diameter to the circumfrence of a circle
#define PI 3.1415


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  double weight, volume, batchWeight, innerA, outerA, area;
  double innerD, outerD, density, thickness;
  double* volume_P, density_P, innerA_P, outerA_P, area_P, thickness_P;
  double* innerD_P, outerD_P;
  int quantity;
  int* quantity_P;


  //variables that point to the corresponding command line arguments beleow:
  innerD = atof(argv[1]);
  outerD = atof(argv[2]);
  thickness = atof(argv[3]);
  density = atof(argv[4]);
  quantity = atoi(argv[5]);

  //Not allowing the user to enter a 0 for quantity must have atleast ONE washer
  if(quantity < 1)
  {
    printf("Quantity can not be less than 1! Try again\n.");
    return 0;
  }

  //setting the pointer equal to the command line input
   *innerD_P = innerD;
   *outerD_P = outerD;

    innerA = PI*pow(*innerD_P/2, 2);
    outerA = PI*pow(*outerD_P/2, 2);
```

Comment: `double* volume_P, density_P, innerA_P,...` only the first one is a pointer.

Comment: wow I thought you could you declare a whole row as pointers. Thank you

Comment: You ever notice how so much professionally written code only seems to declare one var per decl statement, even when they at-least appear they could be chained in one line? Now you know why. It helps avoid things like this from happening. And if you think this was problematic, imagine the subtleness of C++ and references with initialization: `int& r1 = x, r2 = y;` which will compile without problem, including all points of usage of `r1` and `r2`, where changing `r1` changes `x`, but changing `r2` has nothing to do with `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double* volume_P, density_P, innerA_P, outerA_P, area_P, thickness_P;
double* innerD_P, outerD_P;
```

In those lines the `*` only binds to the next variable. It means that the above is actually declaring only the first variable on each line as a pointer and all the rest are `double`.

Change to:

```
double *volume_P, *density_P, *innerA_P, *outerA_P, *area_P, *thickness_P;
double *innerD_P, *outerD_P;
```

Comment: Ahh Ok I was thinking it would make the whole row pointers. I wasn't even thinking that was problem. Thank you so much